# Flutter not showing foreground firebase notifications

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification

I am doing a flutter project and in this project is needed a notification, however when sending the notification it shows it normally if the app is background or closed but it does not show when the app is open.

here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eduflexdchedule"
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <application
        android:label="Label"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </service>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
            

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
           
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is the code on the main.dart

```
    import 'package:project_app/API/Notificator.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 
    'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
    
    import 'package:native_notify/native_notify.dart';
    import 'App.dart';
        
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      // NativeNotify.initialize(96, 'cVRYxxIMoJ4g4UXxgCbr2g');
    
      Firebase.initializeApp();
    
      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
      );
    
      late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
    
      _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    
      
    
   FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
      NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        // print foreground message here.
        print("OVER HERE");
        print('Handling a foreground message ${message.messageId}');
        print('Notification Message: ${message.data}');
    
        if (message.notification != null) {
          print('Message also contained a notification: 
          ${message.notification}');
        }
    
        //.. rest of your code
        NotificationService.showNotification(message);
      });
      runApp(
        MyApp(),
      );
    }
    
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) 
    async {
      print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
      print('Notification Message: ${message.data}');
      NotificationService.showNotification(message);
    }
```

and finally here is the notificator service:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 
'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'package:stacked_services/stacked_services.dart';

class NotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = 
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future initialize() async {
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin 
= FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      // onSelectNotification: doSomething(),
    );
  }

  static Future showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "111",
      "channel",
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      priority: Priority.high,
      importance: Importance.max,
      //largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_launcher"),
      styleInformation: MediaStyleInformation(
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatTitle: true,
      ),
      playSound: true,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        message.data.hashCode,
        message.data['title'],
        message.data['body'],
        NotificationDetails(
          android: androidDetails,
        ));
  }
}
```

some solutions on the site were already attempted but they dont seem to show the notification on foreground

Answer (score 3):

> Android handles incoming notifications differently based on a few different factors. If the application is currently in the foreground, a visible notification is not presented.

As per [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#android-configuration), you can set foreground notifications for Android using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Answer (score -1):

use **onMessageOpenedApp** add *setUpFirebase*:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
```

_handleMessage:

```
void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {

print(message);

}
```